# Hibernate not inserting into joined table because id is null

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a many to many relationship between a User and a Trip entity with two foreign keys. I am trying to add a Trip to the User and even though there is a such an ID in my Users table, I receive the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "UserTrip" violates foreign key constraint "user_id"
  Detail: Key (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "User".
```

User side of the many to many relationship:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "\"UserTrip\"", schema = "\"TransportSystem\"", joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "trip_id") })
private List<Trip> trips = new ArrayList<>();
```

Trip side of the many to many relationship:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "trips")
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

DAO function to add a trip:

```
public void addTrip(int id, Trip trip) {
        executeInsideTransaction(entityManager -> {
            User user = entityManager.find(User.class, id);
            user.getTrips().add(trip);
            });
}
```

My little helper function to handle transactions within the same dao:

```
private void executeInsideTransaction(Consumer<EntityManager> action) {
        EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
        try {
            tx.begin();
            action.accept(entityManager);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            tx.rollback();
            throw e;
        }
}
```

This is where I call to add the trip (don't think any more context is needed, if you wish, I can provide more.)

```
UserService userService = new UserService();
User user = userService.getById(1);
userService.addTrip(1, newTrip);
```

Things to note:

- The entity is "User" but the table it is mapped to is called "Users" since in PostgreSQL the User is a reserved keyword.
- I tried MERGE and REMOVE cascades and a lazy fetch type on the User side
- I tried to pass the whole User object to the addTrip function and then use entityManager.merge() but then as read here on stackoverflow I decided to use entityManager.find() to load the user by id from the database directly and then add a role and commit the transaction. Unfortunately, both cases yield the same result (this exception).
- Needless to say, there is a user_id = 1 in the database.

I would appreciate your input. I know there are many threads regarding this particular exception but honestly I seem unable to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved, to anyone wondering:
The problem comes from the fact that User is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL. I tried multiple times to avoid problems with it, I created a Users table and mapped my User entity to Users table. So far there were no problems with it.

But once a joined table is involved, things get complicated. In my case, I had a UserTrip joined table with a many to many relationship and Hibernate is looking for a user_id from User. I found no way to explicitly tell hibernate to take Users rather than User, that's why I decided to name my table UsersTrip and everything has been resolved.

Lesson learned - avoid using words similiar to keywords where possible.